# "Avoid mutating a prop" warning in vue-chartjs component when prop never changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vuejs2, vue-chartjs

I am extending the `Bar` component from [vue-chartjs](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs) as per their example:

```
// MyChart.js
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default Bar.extend({
  props: ['reportData'],
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: this.reportData,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData);
  },
})
```

But when using the component like so, I'm getting an "Avoid mutating a prop" error when the `testData` variable being passed in changes:

```
<my-chart :report-data="testData"></my-chart>
```

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "reportData"

How could I be mutating the `reportData` prop?

Comment: What would happen if you passed reportData to renderChart instead of passing your local reference-copy?

Comment: @RoyJ I get the same warning

Comment: Does `renderChart` affect its parameter? Do you know what code is being run when the problem is reported?

Comment: @RoyJ It might affect `chartData`, yeah. But it wouldn't be affecting `reportData` right? Even hard-copying via `chartData: {...this.reportData}` gives me the warning. Hard to tell exactly when this is called. `Vue._update` is called up the stack which eventually calls `updateChildComponent` which calls `reactiveSetter` for `reportData`

Comment: Have to fish around: What happens if you call `renderChart` with data that is not derived in any way from `reportData`? Do you still get the warning?

Comment: @RoyJ If I comment out the `this.renderChart(this.chartData)` line, I still get the warning

Comment: Does anything else in your component deal with `reportData`?

Comment: @RoyJ nope that's the whole thing

Comment: @RoyJ I'm thinking this is a bug related to vue router, I'm loading async data to vuex when the route changes and I've found that when I wait to load the router-view component (which contains the chart component) until after the async call is finished, I don't get the warning. I'm going to try submitting an issue on github. Thanks for your attention to this!